# JTextField NetBeans

Tags: java, string, java-swing, jtextfield

Buenas me gustaría saber si alguien me puede decir como podria controlar con el Keytyped que el usuario introduzca solo vocales  y en otro textfield solo consonantes

tengo aqui una referencia que solo me deja letras en general y no numero ni espacios:

```
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if((c<'a' || c>'z') && (c<'A' || c>'Z') && (c<' ' || c>' ')) evt.consume();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el método [.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) de la clase String, acompañado de una expresión regular en cada caso:

```
// Vocales:
String vocales = jTextField1.getText();
if (vocales.matches("[aeiou]+")) {
    // bla bla bla...
}

// Consonantes:
String consonantes = jTextField2.getText();
if (consonantes.matches("[^aeiou]+")) {
    // bla bla bla...
}
```